# Check if adding TimeSpans exceeds TimeSpan.MaxValue

Tags: c#, .net, timespan

I am trying to add some TimeSpans together for some calculations.
eg:

```
var timeSpan1 = new TimeSpan.FromMinutes(1);
var timeSpan2 = new TimeSpan.MaxValue; 
var timeSpan3 = timeSpan1 + timeSpan2;
```

In this case it will exceed the TimeSpan.MaxValue and throw an exception

> System.OverflowException : TimeSpan overflowed because the duration is too long.

What is the correct way to add TimeSpans?

Do I have to put a try-catch around it or write my own extension method?  Seems like this should be part of the .Net framework - either default to MaxValue or have a TryAdd method.

Comment: Why do you think that throwing an exception is not the correct behavior?  Consider that if `timeSpan3` were to result in `TimeSpan.MaxValue`, you'd be breaking the rules of mathematics such that `timeSpan3 - timeSpan1 != timeSpan2`.

Comment: @MattJohnson Good point! However, my use case for MaxValue is to be "infinity". So `infinity + infinity = infinity`. In this case I also shouldn't use `infinity - timespan = ...` and rely on the result.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would use algebra, and keep everything in the `TimeSpan` units:

```
public static TimeSpan AddTimeSpan(this TimeSpan ts1, TimeSpan ts2)
{
    bool sign1 = ts1 < TimeSpan.Zero, sign2 = ts2 < TimeSpan.Zero;

    if (sign1 && sign2)
    {
        if (TimeSpan.MinValue - ts1 > ts2)
        {
            return TimeSpan.MinValue;
        }
    }
    else if (!sign1 && !sign2)
    {
        if (TimeSpan.MaxValue - ts1 < ts2)
        {
            return TimeSpan.MaxValue;
        }
    }

    return ts1 + ts2;
}
```

That way, you can leverage `TimeSpan` without making it convert to other units, and you're assured that the addition will work regardless of other potential gotchas that might come up during conversion (I think it's safe to assume the `TimeSpan` range isn't going to change such that the `TotalMinutes` no longer suffices, but you might run into a bit of inaccuracy in the precise addition result when you get close to the limit of `TimeSpan.MinValue` or `TimeSpan.MaxValue`).

Comment: I ended up switching back to using ticks. The performance hit comparing TimeSpans calling this method 3 or 4 million times was too much

Answer (score 0):

I ended up writing an extension method for TimeSpan. Also needed to check for TimeSpan.MinValue because you can add negative numbers. I started off checking the `Ticks` for the TimeSpans, but I was getting some weird results. Apparently TimeSpan.MinValue.Ticks + TimeSpan.MinValue.Ticks = 2?

So instead:

```
public static TimeSpan AddTimeSpan(this TimeSpan firstTimeSpan, TimeSpan secondTimeSpan)
{
    if (firstTimeSpan.TotalMinutes + secondTimeSpan.TotalMinutes > TimeSpan.MaxValue.TotalMinutes)
    {
        return TimeSpan.MaxValue;
    }
    if (firstTimeSpan.TotalMinutes + secondTimeSpan.TotalMinutes < TimeSpan.MinValue.TotalMinutes)
    {
        return TimeSpan.MinValue;
    }
    return firstTimeSpan + secondTimeSpan;
}
```

Comment: you can check the reference source for hints https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/timespan.cs,574ccdd4f806977f seems to be comparing the sign bits of the Ticks